# Widget on phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, background, widget

We aren't allowed to run applications in phone 7 in background..
So I thought why not create widget..

So My question is : can we as developer create and test widget on phone 7 ? if so how ?

or is there any other alternative for running application in background ?

also what are the technical limitations from a developer point of view for widget when compared to application ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no widgets.

Your only widget-like option would be a live tile app that used push notifications to update the live tile which held the information.

Runs server side though, not background on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no.

With the Mango update coming out later this year they may expose APIs which will allow us to run apps in the background.

Hopefully this feature comes soon!